# Session validation endpoint worked in AM5 but doesn’t work in AM6

Tags: single-sign-on, openam, forgerock

For the last few days I’ve struggled getting AM6(Forgerock Access Management) to work with the same config as AM5. I’m trying to validate a session, after an user performed the OpenID Connect Authorization Code Flow.

**My setup:**

1. I’ve deployed an AM instance
2. Configured OpenID Connect from the Common tasks.
3. Added an OAuth2 client, from Applications -> OAuth 2.0. Setup all configs: redirect uris, scopes lifetimes etc and set “Token Endpoint Authentication Method” to `client_secret_post`
4. (OPTIONAL) Added implied consent to OAuth 2.0 Client, and then set Services -> Oauth2 Provider -> Consent -> `Allow clients to skip consent = true`

**My token usage:**

1. After redirecting the user to the login screen(and receiving the code), I make a POST to the token endpoint (`/oauth2/access_token`) with form_params

   ```
   (
       [client_id] => my_client
       [client_secret] => my_client_pass
       [code] => a5867a21-4d5a-4285-ba07-dcbe46d53bc6
       [redirect_uri] => http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
       [grant_type] => authorization_code
   )
   ```
2. The redirect_uri endpoint receives `access_token` and `id_token`

   ```
   (
       [access_token] => e78569fb-e162-4e4f-ab5e-79ebeaf2ba94
       [scope] => openid offline_access profile email
       [id_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJraWQiOiJiL.......
       [token_type] => Bearer
       [expires_in] => 35999
   )
   ```
3. **(HERE’S THE PROBLEM)** I then check to see if the user’s session, with the given id_token, is still valid (he has logged out or not)
   I make a POST to the sessions endpoint(`/json/sessions`) with

   ```
   (
       'headers' => [
           'Accept-API-Version' => 'resource=1.2'
       ],
       'query' => [
           '_action' => 'validate',
           'tokenId' => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJraWQiOiJiL082T.......
       ],
   )
   ```

When tried against AM5 I get

```
{"valid":true,"uid":"my-user-here","realm":"/"}
```

When tried against AM6.0.0.4 I always get:

```
{"valid":false}
```

Am I missing something which prevents the generated openid id_token to be available in the sessions endpoint?

Comment: Do you have different realms?

Comment: No there was a single default Realm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across the same issue, I've found that I missed an important setting that was added in AM6: **Authorized OIDC SSO Clients**.

This forces your session id to be the same as your id_token from OpenID Connect.

Another solution would be to look into using the `/oauth2/connect/checkSession` endpoint for validating the token